# Динамическая смена изображения кнопки

Tags: java, android

В программе есть кнопки для воспроизведения, то есть текст, а ниже кнопка PLAY.

Реализовал я это так:

```
       ' vplay1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(vecher.this, R.raw.vplay1);
            mp.start();
        }
    });






}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }'
```

Мне теперь нужно сделать следующее:
при нажатии на кнопку PLAY, кнопка заменяется на PAUSE (в том числе меняется иконка изображения).
При нажатии на эту кнопку само собой воспроизведение останавливается.
Еще особенность в том что на одной странице у меня около 20 таких кнопок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может сделать свой флаг? `boolean f = true;`
тогда в коде, при нажатии кнопки

```
if(f){
                // включаете трек, меняете надпись на самой кнопке и ее вид паузу
            } else {
                // выключаете трек, меняете вид кнопка на "play"
            }
            f = !f; // инвертируете флаг
```

Comment: а насчет "20 таких кнопок" (и логично что у всех 100% разный звук, а вид может быть 1", то лучше не onClick, а каждой кнопке отдельно прописать, что происходит при ее нажатии. (если одинаковый вид кнопок), то просто в метод это все, и передавать в нее параметр "трек".

Comment: спасибо за ответ.А как можно без OnClick это все реализовать ?